# Form not submitting when using .replacewith

Tags: python, jquery, sql, flask

Hey I'm attempting to create a form which when submitted the button replaces with a loading wheel using jquery however whenever I run it it with the `.submit("pb")` it doesnt replace the button with a spinner but when I remove the `.submit("pb")` it doesnt submit the form but it replaces the button with a spinner... How do I get it to replace the button with a spinner and submit the form?

## Html code

```
<form id="pb" method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000/simulator">
                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $("button").submit("pb").click(function ()  {
                                    $("button:last").replaceWith( "<div class=\"spinner-border\" role=\"status\"><span class=\"sr-only\">Loading...</span></div>" );
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ladda-progress" data-style="expand-right">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What is `$("button").submit("pb")` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Barmar to be honest I just followed the documentation as I'm super new to any sort of Java, so I thought it was just a button that was supposed to submit the form? I left out the form itself in the code above.

Comment: You didn't leave it out, it's `<form id="pb">`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `submit` event on the form:

```
$("#pb").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(":submit").replaceWith( "<div class=\"spinner-border\" role=\"status\"><span class=\"sr-only\">Loading...</span></div>");
});
```